# New category column based on column value

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to use `if` and `ifelse` statement to create a new column in my dataframe based on the values of an existing column. For example, I have a `variable` column which has numbers from 1 to 10000. I want to categorize them into 8 buckets (using 1250 size) in my new column. So if I have `1` in my column, I should get `b1` in the new column. If I have 9999, I should get `b8`, etc. My if else code is failing so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` :

```
paste0('b', cut(1:10000, 8, labels = FALSE))
```

Replace `1:10000` by column values (`df$colum_name`).